# Left Luggage facilities at Paris Gare du Nord?

Tags: france, luggage, trains, high-speed-rail, paris

I know that most big railway stations in Europe are civilised, and have left luggage facilities. Before I plan part of my day in Paris around it being available though, I thought it was worth checking. Does anyone know if there is a left luggage facility available at Paris Gare du Nord station?

Assuming so, what kind is it? Is it like the one in Milan, where there's a staffed left luggage counter on the station concourse, and you need to be aware that it closes? Or is it like Brussels Midi, where there are just a load of large lockers in racks? (Hiding round the corner on the way to platforms 3-6, if you're looking for them!) Or perhaps even like Cologne (Köln), where there is a nifty underground robotic thingy, where you can drop off or collect your bags from any of the locker-like units?

Oh, and if there is one, is it anywhere near the Eurostar platforms, or am I looking at walking half way back to England to find it on the other side of the (huge!) station...?

Comment: Can someone else confirm that the automatic lockers are open as long as the station is? What is the difference between the manual and automatic lockers if any? Are they the same price/size? Both only accept coins from what I've been reading correct? I have a 24 hour layover in Paris coming up and am scrambling to find a place to store mine and my girlfriends luggage.

Comment: They only take coins, but there are change machines. There are 3 different sizes of lockers, which cost increasing amounts.

Comment: And they are open as long as station is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find information about train stations in France on the [Gares en Mouvement (Stations in Motion)](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/en/) web site. The translation is somewhat haphazard. A left luggage facility is called a *consigne* (*consigne automatique* for automated lockers, or *consigne manuelle* if there's an attendant).

In [Paris Nord](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/en/frpno/accueil/), there are both automated lockers (acessible as long as the station is open, i.e. 4:30–1:00) and a left luggage office (open daily 6:15–23:15). They are on the underground level near the taxi rank, which means they're very close to the exit from the Eurostar platforms. (Paris Nord isn't very big anyway, once you've walked to the front of the train which can be about 400m.)

Comment: There are some details to note about these lockers.
Before entering the area, you will need to submit your luggage to X-ray screening and pass through a metal detector. I think the lockers are one-time lockers, it means that if you want to access your luggage and continue using the locker, you may need to pay again. This was the case last time I used them.

Answer (score 5):

I've used the auto-lockers on this station without any problem. They are open the same time as station is (near all-around clock, with little interval at night) and you can use as you want (I've inserted all my luggage into one locker and saved some money, for example).

Luggage room is on underground level, inside the station, so you don't need to move much far away with your luggage.